# Regex match 10 characters after second pattern

Tags: regex

I would like to match 10 characters after the second pattern:

My String:

```
www.mysite.de/ep/3423141549/ep/B104RHWZZZ?something
```

What I want to be matched:

```
B104RHWZZZ
```

What the regex currently matches:

```
B104RHWZZZ?something
```

Currently, my Regex looks like this:

```
(?<=\/ep\/)(?:(?!\/ep\/).)*$.
```

Could someone help me to change the regex that it only matches 10 characters after the second "/ep/" ("B104RHWZZZ")?

Comment: Just a thought, if you are trying to parse URL then URL's they always contains "/" as resource path, so Why not simply split the url by "/" and you get the Array or List! Then get it.. again this is just another thought.. not about regex that you are looking for

Comment: Just realized that there is a question mark and not a backslash after the string I want to match...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which characters you allow to match. If you want to allow 10 non whitspace characters characters not being `/` or `?` then you could use;

```
(?<=\/ep\/)[^\/?\s]{10}(?=[^\/\s]*$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\/ep\/)` Assert `/ep/` directly to the left
- `[^\/?\s]{10}` Match 10 times any non whitespace character except for `/` and `?`
- `(?=[^\/\s]*$)` Assert no more occurrence of `/` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QpKNdD/1)

Or matching 1+ chars other than `/` `?` `&` instead of exactly 10:

```
(?<=\/ep\/)[^\/?&\s]+(?=[^\/\s]*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HLhBFQ/1)

Answer (score 1):

This would match the string as matching group 1:
`ep\/\w+\/ep\/(\w+)`

https://regex101.com/r/9tUjxG/1

While lookarounds can make this expression more sophisticated so that you won't require matching groups, it makes (in my experiences) the expression hard to read, understand and maintain/extend.
That's why I would always keep regexes as simple as possible.